# How to fix XLConnect's java.lang.NullPointerException on page refresh

Tags: java, r, django, rpy2, xlconnect

I'm using rpy2 to use R in python, specifically to use XLConnect package. The reason is that I want to read a password protected excel file. Other packages are limited both in R and python as I'm using Linux.

So, I've successfully loaded the excel file now using XLConnect.

However, every time I try to refresh my Django project, instead of loading the data it returns `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It works on the first load, then when I refresh the page, the error immediately pops out. Yet, after I left it without refresh for a few mins and refresh the page again, it works normally. The error just happened to immediate page refresh.

It's so frustrating, I thought the error was caused by the error of reading cell (XLConnect's onErrorCell), however, that's just warning.

The line which caused the problem is on assigning the `loadWorkBook` to a variable.

```
import rpy2.robjects as rob
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importrxlc = importr('XLConnect')

xlc_2 = importr('XLConnectJars')

string = """
     wb <- loadWorkbook("my_file_path_here", create=FALSE, password="ddd")
     """
powerpack = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "powerpack")
```

I expect the r code to load again as per normal and read the excel file.

Comment: Try isolating components when trying to find the root of the error. Did you try whether this is working as intended when not running in Djaongo + webserver-associated layer ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yup. It works if i run on python script. It seems that django does not execute the R code on refresh. But if restart the server, then it works fine. It just happen when I refresh immediately.

Comment: I found a solution. When i specify --nothreading on runserver it works. However the performance is so bad without multi threading.

Comment: You may find the short section about multithreading in the documentation interesting ( https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/rinterface.html#multithreading ), and look in the documentation for your web server how to use several processes to compensate for the loss of multithreading.